# what's the difference of md5 and encode in base64 between python and nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, base64, md5, encode

I try to write this Python code in NodeJs, but I find the methods I use `md5` and `encode in base64` in nodeJs, but the output is different from Python's methods.

Anyone to tell me how to deal with this in NodeJs?

```
import md5
def encrypted_id(id):
    byte1 = bytearray('3go8&$8*3*3h0k(2)2')
    byte2 = bytearray(id)
    byte1_len = len(byte1)
    for i in xrange(len(byte2)):
        byte2[i] = byte2[i]^byte1[i%byte1_len]
    m = md5.new()
    m.update(byte2)
    result = m.digest().encode('base64')[:-1]
    result = result.replace('/', '_')
    result = result.replace('+', '-')
    return result
```

this is my JS code:

```
function encryptedId(dfsId) {
    const byte1 = '3go8&$8*3*3h0k(2)2'
    const byte2 = dfsId.toString()
    const byte1_len = byte1.length
    const arr = byte2.split('').map((c,i) => {
        return byte2.charCodeAt(i) ^ byte1[i%byte1_len].charCodeAt(0)
    })
    const newByte2 = String.fromCharCode.apply({}, arr)
    let encode = Util.md5(newByte2)
    return Util.base64encode(encode, true).slice(0, -1)
}
```

Comment: the Util.md5 and Util.base64encode method I used is this https://github.com/node-modules/utility

Comment: It seems like your Python version is replacing '/' with '_' and '+' with '-' after base64 encoding. Is your JS module doing the same thing?